# Grails remoteFunction updating view using templates which has Jquery does recognize elements from templates

Tags: jquery, ajax, templates, grails

I have a view with a button, and when it is clicked it calls remoteFunction(ajax Call) to update a div with a template which has jQuery function associated with it. But that jQuery function does not recognize the elements in the updated div. So the jQuery function is not working correctly to render the view.

**My view** looks like

```
<input type="button" value="Something" id="someButton" class="button" onclick="someFunction()"/>
<div id="updateDiv"> </div>
```

And **js** called when the button is clicked looks like

```
function someFunction() {
    ${remoteFunction(controller:'myController', action:'someAction',update: 'updateDiv'
    )};     
    functionForJQuery();
}
function functionForJQuery(){
    var $someThing = $('.someClassName');
}
```

In **myController**,

```
def someAction= {
    //doSomething
    render (view:"/templates/_myTemplate")
}
```

Finally **_myTemplatetemplate**,

```
<g:textField class="someClassName" value="someValue" />
```

But like I said above, when functionForJquery is called, it does not recognize that textField. Can somebody help me with this, please?

And I also have tried onComplete, or after for the remoteFunction.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the jQuery `.on` (jQuery 1.7 or later) function or the `.delegate` (prior to 1.7) function to use in your selector. These attach the handler to selected elements that are there when the page is first loaded or that are added dynamically.  Something like this:

```
function functionForJQuery(){
    $('body').delegate(".someClassName", "click", function() {
       //do whatever here
    });
}
```

This will attach the function to an element in the `body` with class `someClassName` to the `click` event.

Comment: Note that you may see examples that use .live(), however it is deprecated / not preferred. See here for more infoL http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

In your controller,

try as

```
  def someAction= {
  render template:"/templates/_myTemplate", model:model;
  }
```

instead of

```
 def someAction= {
//doSomething
render (view:"/templates/_myTemplate")
}
```

Good luck